# How do I write XML to an encrypted file?

Tags: c#, xml, encryption

I need to write XML data to an encrypted file. I can read/write encrypted files, but I am having trouble figuring out how to skip the file input part and do it from a MemoryStream object.

This is what I have so far. Basically I just need to get a Byte[] to preform my standard encryption on it.

I appreciate the awesome input. I will be testing this shortly.

EDIT: After testing I am getting a "Cannot access a closed stream" exception when I try and close the memorystream object.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
XmlTextWriter xmlwriter = new XmlTextWriter(ms,Encoding.ASCII);
FileStream EncryptedFileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("AAAAAAAA");
DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("AAAAAAAA");

ICryptoTransform desEncrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(EncryptedFileStream, desEncrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

//create xml document

byte[] bytearray = new byte[ms.Length];
ms.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);

cryptostream.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);

cryptostream.Close();
ms.Close();
EncryptedFileStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write into a MemoryStream and use MemoryStream.ToArray()

Comment: Thank you, I am using the memorystream now

Comment: Figured it out thanks. My second error was closing the objects in the incorrect order.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a StreamWriter that takes in nothing in the constructor. Write to a CryptoStream which has your real destination stream as the target.

Edit: You say "My standard encryption". Are you using standard .NET encryption or did you roll your own algorithm with a custom method? This solution might have a dependency upon you revising it into a ICryptoTransform implementation.

Comment: I posted what I'm trying to do. I am fresh out of school, and this is what they taught us to use in an assignment. I wouldn't be surprised if there was a better way, but I'm trying.